# How to invoke a func passing it as argument between controllers

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a dynamic menu where I send the text and the action of a button from one controller to the next controller and then I want to generate the button that runs the action, but I'm having trouble with the syntax.

So as an example in the first controller i have:

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
         "CompetitiveKPIChart") as! CompetitiveKPIChartViewController

    vc.Menu = [["Menu1":ClickBack()],["Menu2":ClickBack()],["Menu3":ClickBack()]]

func ClickBack() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {});
}
```

and in the second controller:

```
var Menu : [Dictionary<String,()>] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
         let gesture2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: Menu["Menu1"])
    btnBack.addGestureRecognizer(gesture2)
}
```

How can I call the ClickBack() from the first controller in the second controller GestureRecognizer?

Comment: Can't you just pass the second VC a reference to the first one, then call that method on the first one?

Comment: That would not work cause the method on the first might exist on situation 1 but not on situation 2. My idea is to reuse the second view for different contexts. This means in situation 1 we have action1 action but in situation2 we have action2 action with different names.

Comment: There are several problems with your code. 1) a void function should be `() -> ()`, not `()` as you have it. 2) Your `Menu` is an array of single-element dictionaries, but you are referring to it as if it were a dictionary - I think you mean `menu: Dictionary<String, () -> ()>` 3) the second argument (`action:`) to your gesture recogniser initialiser needs to be a `Selector` which is an `@objc` method, not a Swift function. I think I'm going to give up on this and suggest you try another tack!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your `Menu` declaration is wrong - it should be `() -> ()` for a void function, not `()`.

This works in Playground, your syntax does not...

```
var menu : [Dictionary<String,() -> ()>] = [] // Don't use capitals for variables...

func aFunc() {
    print("Hello aFunc")
}

menu = [["aFunc": aFunc]]
menu.first!["aFunc"]!() // Prints "Hello aFunc"
```

However, I think there is a second problem with your code. Your line

`UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: Menu["Menu1"])`

cannot compile, as `Menu` is an array, not a dictionary. I think you probably meant

```
var menu : Dictionary<String,() -> ()> = [:]
```

in which case your set-up code should say

```
vc.menu = ["Menu1":ClickBack, "Menu2":ClickBack, "Menu3":ClickBack]
```

However, there is a final, and probably insurmountable problem, which is that your code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let gesture2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: menu["Menu1"])
    btnBack.addGestureRecognizer(gesture2)
}
```

will still give an error, since `action:` needs to be a `Selector`, which is an `@objc` message identifier, not a Swift function.

I'm afraid I can't see a good way to make this (rather clever) idea work. Time to refactor?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Is there a way to call menu.first!["aFunc"]!()  in a gesturerecognizer? Because I need to generate the menu buttons in a For loop

Comment: There was more than one error in your code - updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry, i think you forgot or mistake writing the menu type var menu : Dictionary<String,() -> ()> = [:] as i get an error on action: menu["Menu1"]

Comment: I was able to achieve what i intended. I made a class MyTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {
    var indexNumb: String?
}     then i added the number in a loop to indexNumb    let gesture2 = MyTapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.invokeIt(_:)))
            gesture2.indexNumb = String(i)   and in InvokeIt i concatenate the string     func invokeIt(_ sender:MyTapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        menu["Menu" + sender.indexNumb!]!()
    }